# sftp with public key is not working

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, public-key

Generated RSA public key using ssh-keygen.

Trying to use to connect remote server through sftp :

```
 JSch jsch = new JSch();
        try {

            String publicKey = "/home/testuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub";
            jsch.addIdentity(publicKey);
            session = jsch.getSession(sftpUsername, sftpHostname, sftpPort);
            session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            logger.error("Unable to obtain session", e);
        }
```

getting below error :

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: /home/testuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
        at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.<init>(IdentityFile.java:261)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:135)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:130)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:206)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:192)
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
jsch.addIdentity(publicKey);
```

JSch javadoc says:

> `public void addIdentity(String prvkey) 
>                  throws JSchException;`
>
> Adds an identity to be used for public-key authentication. Before registering it into identityRepository, it will be deciphered with passphrase.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - prvkey - the file name of the private key file. This is also used as the identifying name of the key. The corresponding public key is assumed to be in a file with the same name with suffix .pub.

You have supplied the public key, when JSch wants the private key.

If you think about it, this makes sense. There's nothing secret about a public key. JSch wants a secret, so it can prove who you are.

Your private key is probably in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (without the `.pub` extension).

You may need to use the two-parameter version of `addIdentity`, in order to supply a passphrase to decrypt the private key.